# Create an aggregate function for GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that outputs results as follows:

```
Person   Food
======   ======
Abner    Apple
Beth     Banana
Beth     Peach
Carlos   Grape
Carlos   Kiwi
Carlos   Strawberry
. .      . .
```

Namely, it associates a person with one or more foods. I'd like the functionality of an aggregate function to choose a food, but none of the built-in aggregates (SUM, MAX, MIN,etc.) really applies to the situation.

If I have a function F() that, given a list of foods, either:

1. provides an ordered list of foods
   based on some optimization
2. provides the optimal unique choice
   from the list

is there any way I can apply a GROUP BY onto it directly?

Does anyone have an example of a query that does this some other way, in case this is a pipe dream?

= = = =

EDIT: Let's say that out of the options shown above, the optimal list is {Kiwi, Grape, Banana, Strawberry, Apple, Peach}, then the output should say:

```
Abner   Apple
Beth    Banana
Carlos  Kiwi
```

i.e., one record per Person, and the Food for each is the first occurrence in the optimal list of a Food associated to that Person in the original table.

Comment: I know you've shown us your current output but can you show what you desired output would be?

Comment: You want to choose a single food out of the group of foods for a given person? What criteria would you use to make that choice?

Comment: If an item does not appear in the Optimal list what should appear in the new query?

Comment: Also how are you determining to show `Beth|Banana` instead of `Beth|Peach` does the order of the fruits appearance in the Optimal list mean something?

Comment: Abe: For my case, all Foods are ranked in terms of optimality; there is no case for non-appearance. For the most general solution, however, use a value of "<none>" for non-appearance.

Comment: Also, the order of the optimal list is the most important thing. Since Banana comes before Peach in that list, Beth is associated with Banana. The ranking is meant to be flexible, however; the ranking in the optimal list above is based on certain characteristics of the food. Under some other criteria, another ranking might apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Person, f.Food FROM MyTable AS t
CROSS APPLY(
SELECT TOP 1 Food FROM MyTable AS t1 WHERE t.Person = t1.Person
ORDER BY <your method of rating and choosing goes here>
) AS f
```

Comment: I think the OP would also want to return the Food associated with each Person?

Comment: Using CROSS APPLY is very likely part of a good soolution, but in my opinion this answer is quite a bit too rough to be of much use to the questioner. Is he seriously going to stick his F() function in the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: I've adapted this solution to my requirement, with a user-defined function that generates a value for each food, and ordering by that value. It's not *entirely* to my liking, but I can work with it. However, is the CROSS APPLY usable in generic SQL, or it is specific to SQL Server?

Comment: @taserian: I don't know if CROSS APPLY is used in other flavors of SQL. Maybe it is a SQL Server thing.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, you want to concatenate those foods?

Try this:

```
select p.Person, stuff((select ', ' + f.Food [text()] from Food f where f.PersonId = p.Id order by f.Food for xml path('')),1,2,'') [Foods]
from Person p
```

Comment: You might want to throw in a `distinct` keyword in the subquery to return distinct "foods".

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in my queries here you can replace the `OptimalFood` table with your F() rowset-returning function (if I'm understanding correctly).

```
WITH PersonFood (Name, Food) AS (
   SELECT 'Abner', 'Apple'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Beth', 'Banana'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Beth', 'Peach'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Carlos', 'Grape'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Carlos', 'Kiwi'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Carlos', 'Strawberry'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Delilah', 'Passionfruit'
), OptimalFood (Priority, Food) AS (
   SELECT 1, 'Kiwi'
   UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Grape'
   UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Banana'
   UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Strawberry'
   UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Apple'
   UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'Peach'
), Choices AS (
   SELECT
      Selector = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY F.Name ORDER BY Coalesce(O.Priority, 2147483647)),
      F.Name,
      Food = Coalesce(O.Food, '<None>')
   FROM
      PersonFood F
      LEFT JOIN OptimalFood O ON F.Food = O.Food
)
SELECT
   Name,
   Food
FROM Choices
WHERE Selector = 1;
```

If you have a table with all the people listed once already, this may be a better way:

```
WITH PersonFood (Name, Food) AS (
   SELECT 'Abner', 'Apple'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Beth', 'Banana'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Beth', 'Peach'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Carlos', 'Grape'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Carlos', 'Kiwi'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Carlos', 'Strawberry'
   UNION ALL SELECT 'Delilah', 'Passionfruit'
), OptimalFood (Priority, Food) AS (
   SELECT 1, 'Kiwi'
   UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'Grape'
   UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'Banana'
   UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'Strawberry'
   UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Apple'
   UNION ALL SELECT 6, 'Peach'
), Person AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM PersonFood
)
SELECT
   P.Name,
   Food = Coalesce(X.Food, '<None>')
FROM
   Person P
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 O.Food
      FROM
         PersonFood F
         INNER JOIN OptimalFood O ON F.Food = O.Food
      WHERE P.Name = F.Name
      ORDER BY O.Priority
   ) X;
```

I would expect that in all these cases you're actually using numeric keys rather than varchar strings. I would *hope*. :)

Comment: The amount of thought put into answering this question deserves +1.

Comment: Thanks, Denis. It really didn't take that long. If Microsoft would give us the First() and Last() aggregate operators like Access has, these queries would be a snap! See [FIRST_VALUE, LAST_VALUE enhancement request on Microsot Connect].(https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254395/over-clause-enhancement-request-first-value-last-value-functions)

Answer (score 0):

You could go without group by with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person, F(Person) AS FoodFunction FROM TableName
```

You'd have to change the function F() so that it takes person (not food list) and get the food list through:

```
SELECT Food FROM TableName
WHERE Person = @Person
```